# Correct Nusach for Ana Bechoach (אנא בכח)

Tags: tefilla, song-poetry

In אנא בכח, I've usually said "בָּרְכֵם, טַהֲרֵם, רַחֲמֵי צִדְקָתְךָ תָּמִיד גָמְלֵם". However, in my Artscroll Siddur I noticed it says רחמם (with a ם instead of י). Which of these are correct?

Answer (score 4):

I've heard there are are sources for both, and I hope someone will answer with more info. I'll just copy what Rabbi *Yaakov* Emden writes in his *sidur*:

> Combine every pair of words, and pause a bit [after each]; say *rachame*, not *rachamim*. But at *kabel rinas am'cha* put all three words together.

Comment: _Shaare T'shuva_ to _OC_ 48 also says to pair the words, though he doesn't say anything about _rachame_.

Comment: The quote from Rav _Ya'akov_ Emden suggests there is a third girsa, not mentioned in the question: _racha_mim rather than _racha_mem.

Comment: The instruction to connect each pair of words should be enough to prove it's _rachame_ and not _rachamem_. The former would be translated as `"bless them [those who seek Your unification], purify them / the mercy of your justice / continually grant them"`, whereas the latter would be `"bless them, purify them / love them. Your justice / continually grant them"`. If we are told where the breaks should be, is it not reasonable to assume they are meant to be phrase boundaries?

Answer (score 2):

The Nusah in the original source of the prayer, Pirkei Heichalos of Rabi Yishmael is "rahamei". I will bli neder source this after Yomtov.

Answer (score 1):

The original Nusah is correct (not Artscroll's). All Sephardic siddurs (with Haskamot from Rab Ovadia Yosef and other Gedolim). Specifically the one which was checked "beiyun rav" by Rabbi Dawid Yosef Shelit"a.

Comment: what is the source?

Comment: The original Nusah is correct because it is that of the AriZal.

Comment: All Sephardic siddurs (with Haskamot from Rab Ovadia Yosef and other Gedolim). Specifically the one made by Rabbi Dawid Yosef Shelit"a.

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to include your sources.

Comment: checked by Rav David Yosef = perfect in every way, shape and form??

Comment: @BaalShemotTovot I would trust it's based on the Nushaot of his father...